# Row aggregations in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a way to get a new column in a data frame in Scala that calculates the `min`/`max` of the values in `col1`, `col2`, ..., `col10` for each row.

I know I can do it with a UDF but maybe there is an easier way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porting [this Python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40875239/9613318) by [user6910411](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910411/user6910411)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, 3, 0, 9, "a", "b", "c")
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "Col7")

val cols =  Seq("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")

val rowMax = greatest(
  cols map col: _*
).alias("max")

val rowMin = least(
  cols map col: _*
).alias("min")

df.select($"*", rowMin, rowMax).show

// +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+---+
// |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|Col7|min|max|
// +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+---+
// |   1|   3|   0|   9|   a|   b|   c|0.0|9.0|
// +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+---+
```

Comment: Why casting to `Float`?  Shouldn't `greatest(cols.map(col): _*).alias("max")` be sufficient?

Comment: @LeoC This is simple safeguard against `null`. If any value in a row is null, then comparison operators evaluate to `null`. If we coalesce to infinity, we can address that.

Comment: I haven't tested the `null` case, but according to the [API doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@greatest(exprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) it's supposed to take care of that: 
`Returns the greatest value of the list of values, skipping null values.`

Comment: @Inna LeoC pointed out, that `least` and `greatest` care take of `null` values automatically. I edited the answer.