# Sum of variable number of columns in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame like this one:

```
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Type|Criteria|Value#1|Value#2|Value#3|Value#4|Value#5|
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  Cat|       1|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|
|  Dog|       2|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|
|Mouse|       4|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|
|  Fox|       5|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

You can reproduce it with the next code:

```
data = [('Cat', 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        ('Dog', 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        ('Mouse', 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        ('Fox', 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
columns = ['Type', 'Criteria', 'Value#1', 'Value#2', 'Value#3', 'Value#4', 'Value#5']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=columns)
df.show()
```

My task is to add Total column that is a sum of all Value columns with # no more then Criteria for this Row.

In this example:

- For row `'Cat'`: Criteria is `1`, so `Total` is just `Value#1`.
- For row `'Dog'`: Criteria is `2`, so `Total` is the sum of `Value#1` and `Value#2`.
- For row `'Fox'`: Criteria is `5`, so `Total` is the sum of all columns (`Value#1` through `Value#5`).

Result should look like this:

```
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
| Type|Criteria|Value#1|Value#2|Value#3|Value#4|Value#5|Total|
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|  Cat|       1|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|    1|
|  Dog|       2|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|    3|
|Mouse|       4|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|   10|
|  Fox|       5|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|   15|
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

I can do it using Python UDF, but my datasets are large, and Python UDF are slow because of serialization. I'm looking for pure Spark solution.

I'm using PySpark and Spark 2.1

Comment: one way to accomplish this without a `udf` would be to turn the Values column into an array, then use `posexplode` to explode the array, filter where the exploded value is <= Criteria, then groupBy and sum. Ping me if this question gets reopened and I can post an answer explaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily adjust the solution to [PySpark: compute row maximum of the subset of columns and add to an exisiting dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40874657) by [user6910411](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910411/user6910411)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

total = sum([
    when(col("Criteria") >= i, col("Value#{}".format(i))).otherwise(0)
    for i in range(1, 6)
])

df.withColumn("total", total).show()

# +-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
# | Type|Criteria|Value#1|Value#2|Value#3|Value#4|Value#5|total|
# +-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
# |  Cat|       1|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|    1|
# |  Dog|       2|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|    3|
# |Mouse|       4|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|   10|
# |  Fox|       5|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|   15|
# +-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

For arbitrary set of order columns define a `list`:

```
cols = df.columns[2:]
```

and redefine total as:

```
total_ = sum([
    when(col("Criteria") > i, col(cols[i])).otherwise(0)
    for i in range(len(cols))
])

df.withColumn("total", total_).show()
# +-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
# | Type|Criteria|Value#1|Value#2|Value#3|Value#4|Value#5|total|
# +-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
# |  Cat|       1|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|    1|
# |  Dog|       2|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|    3|
# |Mouse|       4|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|   10|
# |  Fox|       5|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|   15|
# +-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

**Important**:

Here `sum` is `__builtin__.sum` not `pyspark.sql.functions.sum`.

Comment: @Sergei There isn't. `sum` just reduces collection calling  `__add__` method.