# spark udf max of mutliple columns; TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Row'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to get the max value from a list of columns and the name of the column with hte max value as described in these post
[PySpark: compute row maximum of the subset of columns and add to an exisiting dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874657/pyspark-compute-row-maximum-of-the-subset-of-columns-and-add-to-an-exisiting-da)
[how to get the name of column with maximum value in pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819405/how-to-get-the-name-of-column-with-maximum-value-in-pyspark-dataframe)
I've reviewed a number of posts and tried a number of options but have not been successful yet.

column object not callable [TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable using WithColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305443/typeerror-column-object-is-not-callable-using-withcolumn)
and pass multiple columns [Pyspark: Pass multiple columns in UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540169/pyspark-pass-multiple-columns-in-udf/42540401)

**columns in tables that are loaded to dataframe**
Rule_Total_Score:double,
Rule_No_Identifier_Score:double

```
rules = ['Rule_Total_Score', 'Rule_No_Identifier_Score']
df = spark.sql('select * from  table')

@f.udf(DoubleType())
def get_max_row_with_None(*cols):
    return float(max(x for x in cols if x is not None))

sdf = df.withColumn("max_rule", get_max_row_with_None(f.struct([df[col] for col in df.columns if col in rules])))
```

Answer (score 1):

The UDF accepts a list of columns rather than a `struct` column, so if you pass in the columns and remove `f.struct`, it should hopefully work:

```
@f.udf(DoubleType())
def get_max_row_with_None(*cols):
    if all(x is None for x in cols):
        return None
    else:
        return float(max(x for x in cols if x is not None))

sdf = df.withColumn(
    "max_rule", 
    get_max_row_with_None(*[df[col] for col in df.columns if col in rules])
)
```

Comment: thanks, when I do  sdf.show(50)  I get  An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence?

Comment: @billSt3 that's probably because every column is null/none. You can modify the UDF - see my edited answer.